# Writing a List<ArrayList<String>> into excel sheet

Tags: java, arraylist, selenium-webdriver

I am extracting all the td's of a table in an Array List of String type, once all the td's of each tr's are extracted and displayed as

```
[[0, 14], [1, 1], [5, 6]]
```

Now, I want to write 0, 14 in one row, 1,1 in another and so on.

The function which I am using to extract td's of the table is as below:

```
public List<ArrayList<String>> retrieveTableData(By locator){

    List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements((locator));
    List<ArrayList<String>> rowsData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    for(WebElement row:rows){
        List<WebElement> rowElements = row.findElements(By.xpath(".//td"));

        ArrayList<String> rowData = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(WebElement column:rowElements){
            rowData.add(column.getText().toString());
        }

        rowsData.add(rowData);
    }
    System.out.println(rowsData);
    return rowsData;
}
```

Can someone tell me if there is a simpler way to write this list into excel.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Loop the arraylist and it will print the elements one by one.

```
for (String value : rowsData)
    System.out.println(value);
```

Else convert the arrayList into String array,

```
String[] rowsArr =  rowsData.toArray((new String[rowsData.size()]));

for(String val : rowsArr)
    System.out.println(val);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this a little differently. I would use a two-dimensional array of String so that you can use essentially (col, row) to specify the String that is held in each cell.

```
public String[][] retrieveTableData(By locator)
{
    List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements((locator));
    int rowCount = rows.size();
    int colCount = rows.get(0).findElements(By.xpath(".//td")).size(); // this assumes that all rows have the same number of cols
    String[][] tableData = new String[colCount][rowCount];

    for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
    {
        List<WebElement> cells = rows.get(row).findElements(By.xpath(".//td"));

        for (int column = 0; column < colCount; column++)
        {
            tableData[column][row] = cells.get(column).getText();
        }
    }

    return tableData;
}
```

Once this function returns, you can specify any cell as tableData[col][row] which will make writing the data to Excel easier.

```
String[][] tableData = retrieveTableData(locator);
tableData[1][4]; // the cell contents of column 1, row 4
```